# Facebook Graph API /{page-id}/posts limiting to 600 posts per year

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

While fetching all the posts for 2014 for a few news companies I noticed that the posts seem to cut off at a certain date and jump to the next year.

For example, I am requesting the posts with the following:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/5823419603/posts?limit=100&date_format=U&include_hidden=true&access_token=XXXX

Then using Pagination to go back in time to the previous (and so on and so fourth)
What I see is the following summarization:

```
2015_week_10: 196 Posts
2015_week_09: 232 Posts
2015_week_08: 169 Posts
Total Posts: 597
```

And then to my surprise, the next entry jumps to 2014 (missing a few weeks of 2015)

```
2014_week_53: 115 Posts
2014_week_52: 216 Posts
2014_week_51: 235 Posts
2014_week_50: 32 Posts
Total Posts: 598 Posts
```

And then again, a jump to 2013

```
2013_week_53: 57 Posts
2013_week_52: 95 Posts
2013_week_51: 145 Posts
2013_week_50: 170 Posts
2013_week_49: 130 Posts
Total Posts: 597
```

It stretches out a bit further in 2012 and I get 594 posts between weeks 41 and 53

then in 2011 I get 601 posts between week 6 (Almost made it!) and week 53

I ran this test on a secondary Facebook Page (100362243341518) and got similar results:
599 posts in 2014, 587 in 2013, 599 in 2012 and 600 in 2011

Manually "loading more" in the Facebook Web UI allows me to see that there are posts in the missing time frames.  Insights access to some pages with this issue shows me that there are Impressions on a posts during the missing time frame.

I have scoured the documentation on the Facebook page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed) but found nothing.  There is a mention that the Limit param is upper bounded to 250, but that is per result set, not total (as evidenced by my thousand or so Facebook post pull)

I have looked at numerous StackOverflow articles, and blog articles online, and no one seems to be mentioning anything like this.

I have run this test with both the /posts and /feed edge with the same results.

I have saved the raw CSV files for these posts if someone wanted to look at them let me know, but you will see the same thing that I am noticing.

I am at a complete loss as to why all the posts are not showing up in the API.  Does anyone have some insight on the matter?

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have also added it to facebooks bug tracker (I was looking for that earlier, but apparently I missed that!) https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1624654314422095/

Comment: We're working on this bug report and please follow the bug report for more updates on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug by Facebook, and resolved.  Facebook will be rolling out the fix to all pages.

> Shireesh Asthana ·  · Facebook Team
>
> Hi Jason,
>
> We're in the process of slowly rolling out the fix. We've added the page you provided to the fix. We'll roll it out more openly in the coming weeks. Thanks for the update! Let us know if you have additional questions.
>
> March 23 at 4:29pm ·

See here for more details:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1624654314422095