# Facebook Graph API /{page-id}/posts - only 600 posts per year?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I am writing a wrapper around the Facebook Graph API to collect all the posts made on specific pages.

For some reason, I am only able to query 600 posts per year. When there is more than that on a page, the API does not complain but randomly leaves out posts. To me there is no rhyme or reason which posts are left out: Certain weeks are completely unaffected, while for others I only get a partial amount of posts or none at all.

Carefully reading the API yields this statement:

[The API will return a maximum of 600 ranked, published posts per year.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/page/feed/)

So, it seems like this is intended behavior.

[However, this question from 2015 suggests that this limit is a bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906296/facebook-graph-api-page-id-posts-limiting-to-600-posts-per-year)

Furthermore, I am able to retrieve the full list of posts via the data export of the insights tab in Facebook itself. It seems bizarre to me that I am not able to do the same with the API.

Essentially I have three questions:

- Is the year limit intended behavior?
- If the limit is intended, what determines which 600 posts are returned per year?
- If the limit is intended, is there a way to get around it to retrieve a full list of post(-ids)?

Comment: Quick side note: The data export feature on the insight tab only gives me aggregate data (as of the writing of this comment). Is that new? I don't see a list of all posts there.

Comment: Just checked: It is still possible to access post data via the data export. However, make sure that you explicitly set that you want to export the post data not page data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, I've seen this myself, particularly with pages that publish in high frequency such as newspapers. When retrieving posts historically there can be single days missing, the odd week and sometimes a whole month. The only way to not miss any posts is to call the API daily but this only helps moving forward. Or you can contact me and I'll see if we have the posts you're looking for ;-)

Comment: I do not understand how retrieving the posts daily would help with the problem. When a page with more than 600 posts is queried, random posts are left out to make the limit. This could also include posts for the current day, could it not? So the daily call could also miss posts once the page surpasses the year limit.

Comment: Correct, it won't help for historical posts but it helps going forward. If you get all posts each day, you'll never miss any.

Comment: why did facebook start applying this limit? what is the rationale?

Comment: @JonathanLyon Your comment made sense, and I actually ended up writing something that does that exactly:  Collect all the posts on a regular basis: https://github.com/tomgs/fb-page-aggregator. Thank you!